# Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling Show

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to show multiple labels to another form then it gives me an error here is my codes i guess I must handle the forms visibility to false thanks in advance

```
Public Class Form2
Public lbl As New Label
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub

End Class
```

for loading form2

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    frm2.Visible = True
    If frm2 IsNot Nothing Then

        frm2.Show(Me)            'Show Second Form  

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @MattWilko Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling Show

Comment: show the code you are using for loading form2

Comment: The exception is misleading.  What it actually doesn't like is you changing the *owner* of the form.  frm2.Visible = True already calls Show(), setting it back to False in the Load event doesn't have any effect.  Then it goes kaboom on the Show(Me) call which tries to change the owner to Me.  Just delete that code.  Or replace it with frm2.Owner = Me

Comment: @HansPassant Sir thanks for your reply and possible solution. I already put frm2.Owner = Me as what you have said, the first created label is good but when it comes to the second one it produces the error again.. Thanks